# How to increase the size of disk in Azure via the portal?

Tags: resize, azure-storage, disk, drive, diskspace

I am unable to resize my disk's size on Azure Portal.

The option is disabled even though my machine is in stopped state.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: edited: clarified intent

Answer (score 0):

You can try with PowerShell. The script you need is:

```
$vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.DiskSizeGB = 1023
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VM $vm
```

For better understanding check this link [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk)